# How to configure Gradle's incremental build with annotation processor

Tags: java, gradle, querydsl, incremental-build, annotation-processor

I want to use QueryDSL annotation processor as a part of my build process. How can I **get rid of unnecessary annotation processor compile&run everytime i change any class?** I want QueryDSL to generate Q-* classes only if some related classes are changed.

This always running annotation processor has negative impact on our build process time and it looks like incremental building is not working if annotation processor has to run.

Thank you.

Comment: So it works with my simple annotation processor watching files in one hardcoded directory. Speed up ~2-3 times for every run!! Hope Gradle will solve it in general for all annotation processors :) Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. However i don't think Gradle can solve it universally because it can never know which files AP needs as its input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle cannot know which files annotation processors use **as their input** so it has to trigger full recompilation every time something in watched directory changes (src).

However you can easily tell Gradle which files should only trigger annotation processing. Change to other files **will not trigger use of annotation processors** and gradle can use all its power (e.g. incremental builds).

I also added "force" task **buildWithAP** calling annotation processors regardless of hint (heuristic) function result.

**My solution:**

```
ext.isTask = { name -> return project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(name) }

/**
 * Heuristic function allowing to build process guess if annotation processor run is necessary
 * Annotation processors will not be called during build task if this function returns FALSE
 */
ext.isApInvalidated = { -> return hasAnyFileRelatedToApChanged() }

dependencies {
  if (isTask("buildWithAP") || isApInvalidated()) {
    println "Going to run annotation processors ..."
    apt "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$queryDslVersion:jpa"
  ...
  } else {
    // just add generated classes to the classpath
    // must be in else branch or multiple AP calls will collide!
  sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += projectDir.absolutePath + "/build/generated/apt"
  }
```

}

```
task buildWithAP (dependsOn: build) {}
```

You can use any annotation processor you want, for example your own, not just QueryDSL.

Hope my point is clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's more complicated than that but Gradle will soon publish a work around. It has been announced at Gradle summit this year. Your solution is suboptimal as it triggers full builds has soon as annotation processing is required. What would be valuable is incremental annotation processing in this case. Also, the heuristic to determine if a file using annotations should be recompiled is too simplistic, some APs might well have advanced processing and it could be very hard to identify this files. Not to mention in most cases you need to grep all files for annotations..

Comment: And even if you could be able to work around all that, you would still require a full dependency analysis of dependencies so that if one of the file inside the transitive closure of a file that triggers AP is changed, it would also invalidate the file itself (as the compiler does).

Comment: Of course it is not a final solution, but it works for our custom AP and QueryDSL's one as well. 

My hasAnyFileRelatedToApChanged() is just based on file change timestamp comparison.

If file used by AP really changes, full build with AP run is triggered. However it is much better than trigger it everytime ;)

I'm looking forward to official solution but for now it is the best i figured out.

Comment: For example we follow a common practice having suffix *Entity on entity files. These files are in most (or maybe all) cases those you only need to watch for changes. If it changes, trigger QueryDSL's AP. If not, leave it alone (=fast). So for querydsl we watch: `fileTree(dir: 'src', include: '**/*Entity.java')`

Comment: It can work, but it highly depends on the nature of your AP. If you AP doesn't need any other file than the one containing the annotation to perform its job (i.e. generating code), then yes, you're definitely in a case where things are simpler and your workaround might boost your build times.

Comment: If my AP needs any file which can be somehow identified (suffix / contain annotation / folder / ...) it helps a lot. I'm sure you can have not so easily determinable files but in that worst case you will end up with the same time as you would have without this heuristic. Provided heuristic function can only make your builds faster. As faster as your heuristic is :)

What workaround will be published by Gradle and when?  How will it solve problem with "black box" AP using "some random" input files?

Comment: I find that the build cache is easily confused by annotation processing. Ffor example create a Dagger injectible class, checkout a branch without class, rebuilding will use cache that contains generated class pointing to non-existant class.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is currently not possible: see this [blog post](https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance) - section *"Incremental compile with annotation processors"*:

> ...with annotation processors, Gradle does not know which files they are going to generate. Neither does it know where and based on what conditions. Therefore Grade disables the Java incremental compiler if annotation processors are in use

Related issue for Gradle: [Make incremental compile efficient in the presence of Annotation Processors #1320](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1320)

The Blog post also mentions a possible Workaround:

> It is however possible to limit the impact of this to the set of classes that really use annotation processors. In short, you can declare a different source set, with a different compile task, that will use the annotation processor, and leave the other compile tasks without any kind of annotation processing

However, this seems to be quite some work, so I haven't used this yet.

Comment: Thank you, i also found that blog post. It is a pity that Gradle does not inform developer about skipping incremental processing because of annotation processor in effect. 

However i figured out how to solve it. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The issue seems to have been solved! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37079915